# Rails Engines: engine views or partials as reusable widgets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, rails-cells

Our team is starting to use a lot of engines, and we would like these to display "widgets" when the user logs in the main or host app. We already use the [public activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem to some extent.

Essentially, what we need is to for the host app to loop through each mounted engine, and then if the engine has "widgets", the host app should render them. Ideally, the engine should tell the app how to render the views.

I found the [Cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) gem to be promising, but it requires the host app to know exactly what cells to render. (I think one quick way around this is for the engine to tell the app the path.)

What MVC, Rails, etc. pattern(s) should I look into?